# Using javascript media queries to change position of HTML elements based on viewport heights/widths

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reposition my landing page's title and subtitle elements by adjusting where their container is located on the webpage based on different viewport heights and widths. I am trying to achieve this using media queries via Javascript, but I am not quite sure if I am doing it correctly. The code as it stands looks like so:

```
function screen(small_screen, small_med_screen, med_screen, med_large_screen, large_screen) {
  if (small_screen.matches) { // If media query matches
    $("#index-container").style.top="20vh";
    } 
  else if (small_med_screen.matches) {
  $("#index-container").style.top="30vh";
    }  
  else if (med_screen.matches) {
  $("#index-container").style.top="40vh";
    }  
  else if (med_large_screen.matches) {
  $("#index-container").style.top="60vh";
    }  
  else if (large_screen.matches) {
  $("#index-container").style.top="70vh";
    }

var small_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:400px) and (max-width: 150px)")
var small_med_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:500px) and (max-width: 250px)")
var med_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:450px) and (max-width:400px)")
var med_large_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:550px) and (max-width:500px)")
var large_screen = window.matchMedia("(min-height:600px) and (min-width:600px)")
screen(small_screen, small_med_screen, med_screen, med_large_screen, large_screen)
```

I also know I should add an event listener to adjust if I resize the window, but am not sure how to pass arguments to the listener function. Thank you!

Comment: Any reason you're using JS instead of plain CSS? Also `$("#` implies you're using jQuery. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there! You should use jQuery's `.css()` method to change the CSS properties instead of `.style`

You can define the media queries inside the function and simply call the function on window resize without needing to pass any arguments.

```
function screen() {
  var small_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:400px) and (max-width: 150px)");
  var small_med_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:500px) and (max-width: 250px)");
  var med_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:450px) and (max-width:400px)");
  var med_large_screen = window.matchMedia("(max-height:550px) and (max-width:500px)");
  var large_screen = window.matchMedia("(min-height:600px) and (min-width:600px)");

  if (small_screen.matches) {
    $("#index-container").css("top", "20vh");
  } else if (small_med_screen.matches) {
    $("#index-container").css("top", "30vh");
  } else if (med_screen.matches) {
    $("#index-container").css("top", "40vh");
  } else if (med_large_screen.matches) {
    $("#index-container").css("top", "60vh");
  } else if (large_screen.matches) {
    $("#index-container").css("top", "70vh");
  }
}

$(window).resize(screen); // Add event listener
screen(); // Call function on page load
```